C# not inferring nullability of underlying types on function with type parameters
Just for clarification, this is a purely type system related question - I only want to know if I'm messing up with the C# language and if there's anything that I can do to make it infer some types more strictly and accurately.
I came from a JavaScript/TypeScript background, and there, the main asyncrhonous components are Promises. To perform multiple asyncronous calls, without the next one waiting for the previous to finish, we can use Promise.all. If we're using TypeScript, its compiler will infer the underlying types of each promise with strictness, like this:
async function getFn<T>(): Promise<T> {
  return {} as T // just to compile
}

type T1 = {
  value: string
}
type T2 = {
  value: string
}
type T3 = {
  value: string
}

async function operation() {
    const tuple = await Promise.all([
        getFn<T1>(), // this is Promise<T1>
        getFn<T2>(), // this is Promise<T2>
        getFn<T3 | undefined>(), // this is Promise<T3 | undefined>
    ]) // The "tuple" variable type is inferred, by TypeScript, to be [T1, T2, T3 | undefined]

  console.log(tuple[0].value) // Ok
  console.log(tuple[1].value) // Ok
  console.log(tuple[2].value) // Compile error - "Object is possibly 'undefined'"
}

In C#, after some research, I realized that I can do something similar with this:
public class Program
{
    private static Task<T> GetFn<T>()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(default(T)!);
    }
    
    private record T1(string Value);
    private record T2(string Value);
    private record T3(string Value);
    
    public static async Task Operation()
    {
        var taskT1 = GetFn<T1>(); // this is Task<T1>
        var taskT2 = GetFn<T2>(); // this is Task<T2>
        var taskT3 = GetFn<T3?>(); // this is Task<T3?>
        
        await Task.WhenAll(taskT1, taskT2, taskT3);
        
        var tuple = (await taskT1, await taskT2, await taskT3);
        
        Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1.Value); // Ok
        Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item2.Value); // Ok
        Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item3.Value); // Compiler warning - "Dereference of a possibly null reference"
    }
}


So far so good. As you can see, the C# solution is a bit repetitive, requiring us to manually declare each variable. The problem arose when I tried to create a custom utility function that abstracts this C# solution, making it closer to the Javascript one. The function I created was this:
public static class TaskUtils
{
    public static async Task<(T1, T2, T3)> ResolveAll<T1, T2, T3>(Task<T1> t1, Task<T2> t2, Task<T3> t3)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3);
        
        var v1 = await t1;
        var v2 = await t2;
        var v3 = await t3;
        
        return (v1, v2, v3);
    } // This function has a bunch of overloads that does the same thing but with more/less parameters and parameter types
}

But now, when I try to use this function and I have a Task that resolves to a nullable underlying type, I have this problem right here:
public class Program2 
{
    private static Task<T> GetFn<T>()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(default(T)!);
    }
    
    private record T1(string Value);
    private record T2(string Value);
    private record T3(string Value);
    
    public static async Task Operation2()
    {
        var tuple = await TaskUtils.ResolveAll(GetFn<T1>(), GetFn<T2>(), GetFn<T3?>());
        
        Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1.Value); // Ok
        Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item2.Value); // Ok
        Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item3.Value); // Also ok - The inferred type is T3, not T3?
    }
}

As you can see, the C# compiler lets me freely access values fromm Item3, even though it might initially be null. I ran into this problem got null pointer exceptions at runtime.
Why can't C# infer nullability of underlying generic types like this?

Interestingly, Resharper does warn about this: "Dereference of a possibly null reference".

I used https://sharplab.io/ to reproduce this issue. Can you tell me which version of Resharper are you using?

I'm using the most recent version

Why are you awaiting your Tasks twice? Have you checked what Task.WhenAll() returns?
